# Embed Joomla module within component

Tags: joomla1.5, joomla-component, joomla-module

I have an instance of 'breadcrumbs' module created on my site, set to be displayed at 'customposition'. There is a component which has a series of web pages written in HTML. How do I specify the location of customposition in those webpages, so that joomla displays the module within my component?

Regards,
Abhi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it! JModuleHelper to the rescue :)

http://www.minitek.gr/tutorials/joomla-16-tutorials/joomla-api-tutorials/item/203-how-to-insert-a-module-position-inside-a-joomla-component.html

Here's the code from the link:

```
$modules =& JModuleHelper::getModules('position_name');
foreach ($modules as $module){
echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($module);
}
```